# Is there a way to do a GKE backup of secrets only in a cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The pricing of GKE backup is based on the number of pods that are being backed up.
I would like to backup secrets on my cluster only. This is all I need to back up to decrease my GKE backup bill significantly.
Is there a way to only backup secrets and not all the pods on the cluster?

Comment: Seems like this link could help you: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/add-on/backup-for-gke/how-to/protected-application

Comment: Thanks also looked into it but wasn't sure if that would still include the pod. Will give it a try and post an answer to my own question

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. When you select your protected application within the cluster it still includes all Kubernetes resources, which would include all pods.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja are your queries addressed if you still have some issues or queries revert back if you still need some help.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja are your queries addressed if you still have some issues or queries revert back if you still need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `Backup for GKE Secrets only` then there isn’t any possibility for achieving your desired outcome, instead you can write a script for taking the backup of the secrets and store them in GCS  buckets.

The actions you need to do are create a script that takes backup of your kubernetes secrets to your GCS storage, create a kubernetes job which will run this script and use kubernetes scheduler for taking periodic backups. In this [**official documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) there are some sample snippets which might help you for pushing your backups to GCS.

You can use the below command for getting all secrets. Use your python code for running this command, save the output to a file and generate yaml files of each secret and store them in your GCS bucket.

```
kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces
```